# docker basics: docker run -it with or without /bin/bash

Tags: bash, docker

I am self-studying docker basics and I am not sure what's the difference when we use "docker run -it centos" vs  "docker run -it centos /bin/bash". I tested two commands and both of them seem to start a centos terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See next:

> Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

The `/bin/bash` after image is called `COMMAND`, but for `centos`, the default command already defined in `Dockerfile`, see [this](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/blob/ccd17799397027acf9ee6d660e75b8fce4c852e8/docker/Dockerfile#L4):

```
FROM scratch
ADD centos-8-x86_64.tar.xz /
LABEL org.label-schema.schema-version="1.0"     org.label-schema.name="CentOS Base Image"     org.label-schema.vendor="CentOS"     org.label-schema.license="GPLv2"     org.label-schema.build-date="20201204"
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

So, the situation you mentioned above same here.

Comment: Nice explanation... Thank you!